# Django/Python email notification for events

Tags: python, django, email, notifications, reminders

I work on a page in Django, where users can set custom reminders for different dates (max. 3 per date). The reminders should send via e-mail. Its  similar to Google Calendar, where you can set multiple reminders for each event in x-minutes, x-hour or x-days before the date starts.
I wonder, how I can solve it combined with Django. Since there will be a lot of users and dates, which should of course also run perfomant.
Should I do this with a cron job? Is there a python way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The other traditional way is to use django-celery: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery/

You can use the **celerybeat** command to run periodical tasks. Also you can start pending tasks from a django view.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a cron job. To create a management command: refer to the [documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/)

Also, you can create the email generation as a queue based, distributed implementation for enhanced performance. You can use [Django-mailer](http://code.google.com/p/django-mailer/) app for the same.